# Android InputType, как определить, что текстовое поле - для ввода email

Tags: android

`EditorInfo` в классе, который `implements InputMethodService`, требуется определить тип поля (поле электронной почты, пароля, обычное текстовое и т.д.).

Работает код для обычного поля и для пароля:

```
public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);
    attribute.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;

    int variation = attribute.inputType & EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION;
//для обычного текста включена заглавная буква
    if ((attribute.inputType & attribute.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) == 1) {
        setRegister(true);
    }
//для пароля выключена
    if (variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
            || variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
            || variation == 0xe0 /* EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD */
            ) {
        if ((attribute.inputType & EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) == EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) {
            setRegister(false);
        }
    }
//с имейлом проблемы, код не работает
    if((attribute.inputType & attribute.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
    & attribute.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME
            & attribute.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT
    & attribute.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS) == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "email!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Помогите применить флаги и инты, которые используются при определении поля для ввода электронной почты!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось. Смешно до глупости, ну да ладно.
Пара нюансов

```
if (variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS ||
            variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS||
            variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT) {
        if ((attribute.inputType & EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) == EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) {
            setRegister(false);
        }
    }
```

Учитываем все возможные варианты флагов поля.
Ну и когда тестим, убеждаемся, что подопытное поле inputType = email :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно по идее загнать в метод строку на проверку валидности мыла, если придет true, то поле явно является email-ом

```
public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return target != null && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Получается, что этот метод вызывается в момент тыка на поле. Этот способ немножко не подходит.
Тык в поле, выползает кастомная клава, и надо ей сказать, делаем ли заглавной первую букву или нет. Я подумала сделать по аналогии с первыми ифами, но моего понимания не хватает для корректного использования флагов и интов EditorInfo.